# Dict with 2 keys, Find max value of 1 key while keep the other steady

Tags: python, for-loop, max

I have a dictionary `n[i,j]` in Python. I want to find each max value of the dict for every `i`.

The dict looks like this:

```
n[1,1]=3
n[1,2]=4
n[1,3]=7
n[2,1]=5
n[2,2]=64
n[2,3]=32
n[3,1]=21
n[3,2]=21
n[3,3]=45
```

I want to get the max value for every `i`. In this case 
for `i=1` the max is `n[1,3] = 7`, and
for `i=2` the max is `n[2,2] = 64`,
and so on.

Comment: Do you mean n[i][j] ? or n[(i,j)] ?

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: to be honest, I have no clue how to do that. I only know how to get the max value overall: `nmax=max(n,key=lambda key:n[key])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this over several lines for clarity, but if you have a taste for one-liners you can probably do it in a nested dict comprehension:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> result = defaultdict(list)
>>> for (i,j),v in n.items():
    result[i].append(v)
>>> for i,v in result.items():
    print (i,max(v))
1 7
2 64
3 45
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but that doesnt work. I get a key error for the key 3...

Comment: @Angriffskeule In what line of your code do you get a key error for 3? I originally pasted the code out of IDLE and I just pasted the posted code back into IDLE. It works.

Comment: I did copy and paste and tried again. Now I get an error message for the last line: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: You have redefined list as a variable. Don't do that. Start your interpreter session afresh and start over.

Comment: thats it, it works. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
max = [0] * N
for i in range(N):  
    for j in range(N):
        if n[i, j] > max[i]:
            max[i] = n[i, j]
```

Comment: what is `N` supposed to be?